# How to disable IPv6 ping response in Linux without firewall

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, ping, icmp

How can I disable IPv6 ping responses in Linux without using the IPv6 firewall?

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/454545/deny-ping-response-in-ipv6) covers how to do this using the IPv6 firewall via `iptables`, but I'm using an embedded system that doesn't currently have firewall support, so I need an alternate method.

I'm able to disable IPv4 ping response by simply setting `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all` from 0 to 1. Is there something like this for IPv6?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Add to **/etc/sysctl.conf**

```
# IGNORE/DISABLE PING FOR IPV4/IPV6
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1
net.ipv6.icmp.echo_ignore_all = 1
```

Apply changes

`/sbin/sysctl -p`

**Solution 2**

IGNORE/DISABLE PING FOR IPV4/IPV6 TEMPORARILY

Execute commands in bash:

**IPV4**

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all`

**IPV6**

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/icmp/echo_ignore_all`

Apply changes

`/sbin/sysctl -p`